# Is it better to say "I and I alone (am working on)" or "I alone (am working on)" when saying that I am the only one working on something?

Tags: comparison

In the context of saying that I am the only person working on something, is it better to say:

1. "**I and I alone** am working on...

or

2. "**I alone** am working on...

Comment: If it's a simple statement, _I alone_ is sufficient. _I, and I alone_ is a rather dramatic way of stressing that you did something singlehanded.

Comment: Notice too that even just “I alone...” is formal and declaratory. In conversation or in an informal email a native speaker would be more likely to say, *I’m the only one working on...*

Comment: Great comments! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible answers are:

"*I alone* am working on..." or "*I'm the only one* working on..."